# gradientDrawable for showing the textview in a colored circle

Tags: android

I am using gradientDrawable to display the textview in a colored circle. I am using the following code -

```
gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
gradientDrawable.setColor(nColor1);
viewHolder.textview.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
view.invalidate();
gradientDrawable.invalidateSelf();
```

This however draws a circle for the textview based on the size of the textview. I have a problem here -

When the textview is something like `1h22m`, the circle gets big to fit this in it. When the textview is `0`, the circle is very small and is not appearant to the user. Can I draw circles of standard size irrespective of the size of the textview. How do I this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a `TextView` inside a `ViewGroup` ie. `RelativeLayout` and set background to this `ViewGroup`. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_view_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I wanted to set size of gradientdrawable in java code itself. A standard size for all textviews

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from setting the background of `RelativeLayout` in code. And if you want the same size of circle every time, then set constant size to `RelativeLayout`